# how to insert data to an HTML div

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have a script which renders a sql query object to the view page.
I am trying to retrieve the firstname from that object and want to print it on the UI.

I have function which does

```
 res.render(
      'login',
      {"data": data});
```

the data has a row

```
 [{id:9, user_name:'abc', email:'abc@ask.com', password: '1234', firstname: 'monica', lastname:'than'}]
```

I am passing this to an .ejs file where I am getting the firstname 'monica' like below:

```
 <body> 
 <h1> Welcome! </h1><p id="pil"></p>  
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>       
    <h3>Search for Pilgrim </h3>  
 <script>
    var name = <%- data[0].firstname %>
    document.getElementById("pil").innerText=  <%- data[0].firstname %>;
</script>      
</body>
```

the name is getting value monica - as observed from debugger console.[image]

But I dont get this printed on the UI anywhere.

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong over here??

Comment: make http://jsfiddle.net/ please...

Comment: You are missing quotes around Monica.  `var name = "<%- data[0].firstname %>"`

Comment: U mised semicolen after `name = <%- data[0].firstname %>`

Comment: my name variable has monica in it even if I have not given semicolon

Comment: tried with quotes too. my name variable now became "monica" instead of just monica

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
document.getElementById("pil").innerHTML=" <%- data[0].firstname %>";
```

Comment: use innerHTML instead of innerText

Comment: I still do not get it..!

I have tried `document.getElementById("pil").innerHTML=" <%- data[0].firstname %>";`

Comment: now my debugger console shows --

<p id="pil"></p>

var name = monica
document.getElementById("pil").innerHTML= "monica";

Comment: the pil paragraph is still shows empty though  variable 'name' has monica in it

Comment: just change <p> tag to <div> and check whether it is working or not

Comment: I did change to div. still empty
from Ui debugger console:
<div id="pil"></div>

Comment: @MonicaThaneer: May be there are more than one element having id="pil"

Comment: @sanki I just have one div with id "pil" :-|

Comment: Try changing the id, alert the variable name "alert(name);" to confirm

Comment: @MonicaThaneer Hey you just want to display the name in <p> tag only ryt?  Change your code to <h1> Welcome! </h1><p id="pil"><%- data[0].firstname %></p>  .Without using javascript try directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using:

```
var name = "<%- data[0].firstname %>";
document.getElementById("pil").innerText=  name;
```

As there's only one element with `id="pil"`

I think the problem is with wrapping the code in the function, may be you should try this:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

and js be like:

```
function myFunction() {
  var name = "<%- data[0].firstname %>";
  document.getElementById("pil").innerText=  name;  
}
```

Here's the working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pekuwxqn/1/)